Role of Uniform Summability in a Generalized Central Limit Theorem
In the generalized central limit theorem (Theorem 21.2), the statement is as follows:

Theorem 21.2 (Central Limit Theorem):
Let $(X_j)_{j \geq 1}$ be independent (but not necessarily identically distributed) random variables such that $\mathbb{E}[X_j] = 0$ for all $j$, and let $\mathbb{V}[X_j] = \sigma_j^2$. Assume:
1.
$$
\sup_j \mathbb{E}[|X_j|^{2+\epsilon}] < \infty \quad \text{for some } \epsilon > 0,
$$
2.
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sigma_j^2 = \infty.
$$
Then:
$$
\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma_j^2}} \xrightarrow{d} Z,
$$
where $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n X_j$, convergence is in distribution, and $Z \sim N(0, 1)$.

The proof of this theorem is said to rely on Paul Lévy's continuity theorem and is essentially the same as the classical CLT. However, I’m having trouble understanding the role of the uniform summability condition $\sup_j \mathbb{E}[|X_j|^{2+\epsilon}] < \infty$ in the proof.
How does this condition come into play, and why is it necessary?
Any clarification or detailed reference would be greatly appreciated!
Here is a sketch of the proof. Let $\varphi_j(u)$ denote the characteristic function of $X_j$, which is given by:
$$
\varphi(u) = 1 - \frac{\sigma_j^2}{2} \cdot u^2 + u^2 \cdot o(1).
$$
Define
$$
Y_n = \frac{1}{\left( \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sigma_j^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i.
$$
Then:
$$
\varphi_{Y_n}(u) = \prod_{j=1}^{n} \varphi_j\left(\frac{u}{\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right),
$$
which expands to:
$$
\varphi_{Y_n}(u) = \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log\left(1 - \frac{\sigma_i^2}{2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i^2} u^2 + \frac{u^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2} \cdot o(1)\right)\right).
$$
Using the Taylor expansion of the logarithm, we get:
$$
\varphi_{Y_n}(u) = \exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2} + \frac{u^2 \cdot n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2} \cdot o(1)\right).
$$
At this point, I am unsure how to justify why the last term in the exponent,
$$
\frac{u^2 \cdot n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2} \cdot o(1),
$$
goes to zero. Could someone provide insight into how this step is rigorously justified, and whether the uniform summability condition $\sup_j \mathbb{E}[|X_j|^{2+\epsilon}] < \infty$ plays a role in ensuring this convergence?
Any help or references to a detailed explanation would be greatly appreciated!
